# is it okay to flatten a slightly curved 2x4 against the wall with lag screws?

Tags: carpentry

I bought a slightly curved (0.3 inch elevation in one corner if I lay it flat) 2x4 that I bought in order to mount a hanging bar on it. I need it to be flush against the wall so that it aligns with another 2x4 to form a flat surface.

Is it okay if I use lag screws with washers to force the 2x4 completely flat against the wall?

Comment: No.  When you least expect it, it will spontaneously burst into flames due to the internal stress caused by the lag bolts. JUST KIDDING of course. You'll be absolutely fine taking out a small warp with lag bolts & washers. If you're stressing about it, 2x4s are pretty cheap, just buy another one that's straight.  But you'll be fine with the one you have.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Had me worried after I read your first sentence. :-)  Stay safe out there.

Comment: I would bet it's going to dig into the drywall at the corners.

Comment: @JACK  LOL, thanks for the comment. Just bending the rules here a bit to add some humor during these trying times.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like a pic but if it's typical construction-garbage grade then I think so.  If you just force it flat with your hand then how much pressure does it take?  If you can do that and it goes flat then once you bolt it down (how thick is your drywall and how long are the lags?) after a year of exposure to the environment in the house it will "warp flat"